# Acess response outside function AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can I access response object outside function in AngularJS and use outside function.

```
$http.get("secure/cases/"+caseid).success( function(response) {
            $scope.data = response;
        });
```

//and use here response

```
  var single_object = $filter('filter')(response.correspondences, function (d) {return d.id;})
```

Thank you.

Comment: `$http` is asynchronous. You need to consume response within the callback

Answer (score 0):

```
var single_object = $filter('filter')($scope.data.correspondences, function (d) {return d.id;});
```

Be careful! $http works async, thus it's possible that $scope.data is not defined if the GET request is still busy.

This works fine:

```
$http.get("secure/cases/"+caseid).success( function(response) {
    $scope.data = response;
    $scope.singleobject = $filter('filter')(response.correspondences, function (d) {return d.id;})
    });
```

In the example above, singleobject is in your $scope, usable in the views/partials where this $scope is coupled.